# Display an array in a readable/hierarchical format

Tags: php, sql

Here is the code for pulling the data for my array

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mutli_page_form');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wills_children WHERE will=73";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data = unserialize($row['children']);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
?>
```

When I use print_r($data) it reads as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Natural Chlid 1 [1] => Natural Chlid 2 [2] => Natural Chlid 3 ) )
```

I would like it to read as:

Natural Child 1
Natural Child 2
Natural Child 3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($data[0] as $child) {
   echo $child . "\n";
}
```

in place of `print_r($data)`

Comment: thanks for the response but it prints out the data as "Array"

Comment: `<?php foreach($data[0] as $child) {
   echo $child . "<br />";
}?>`

this worked great thanks Brian !

Comment: why on earth is this the chosen answer when <pre></pre> is the obvious choice?

Comment: > why on earth is this the chosen answer? Engineers :-)

Comment: This will not work if you have a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Alesana Yep, but OP didn't have a multidimensional array. I think as others have commented on this answer the way you want to go is `<pre>print_r($data)</pre>`. Always fun to see a new comment on a 5+ year old answer though! :)

Comment: Ah, in my case I was working with a multidimensional array. I haven't left a comment before so when I saw no one else had pointed this out I thought it might be a perfect opportunity!

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, how about another 4 years :D? Thanks for pointing out Pre, pre, though. I don't search much further than the answer most of the time.

Answer (score 481):

Instead of

```
print_r($data);
```

try

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($data);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that you can pass `true` as the second parameter to print_r to get the data as `string`. Now you can `return '<pre>'.print_r(User::all(), true);` from your routes file.

Comment: I like this answer too but the OP only wanted the Strings to print, and not the array indices (it seems like). And only 1-dimensional data. I usually only do this to check a recordset of data before I continue with a solution, so this solution works way better for stuff like that.

Answer (score 83):

```
print("<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>");
```

Comment: This is ideal as it does not add unnecessary whitespace around your data.

Answer (score 56):

I have a basic function:

```
function prettyPrint($a) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}

prettyPrint($data);
```

**EDIT:** Optimised function

```
function prettyPrint($a) {
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($a,1).'</pre>';
}
```

**EDIT:** Moar Optimised function with custom tag support

```
function prettyPrint($a, $t='pre') {echo "<$t>".print_r($a,1)."</$t>";}
```

Comment: Best answer so far, and you can even optimize it more if it's used very often with comma : `echo '<pre>',print_r($a,1),'</pre>';`

Answer (score 25):

I think that `var_export()`, the forgotten brother of `var_dump()` has the best output - it's more compact:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export($menue);
echo "</pre>";
```

By the way: it's not allway necessary to use `<pre>`. `var_dump()` and `var_export()` are already formatted when you take a look in the source code of your webpage.

Comment: I agree about var_export, but I've had to combine it with <pre></pre> because it wasn't outputting the results in the proper format.

Comment: @Chaya-Cooper It's not properly formatted on the displayed page, but I think Hexodus meant it's formatted "in the _source code_ of your web page" -> try menu "view source", or Ctrl-U in Firefox

Comment: One benefit of this approach is that the output is formatted as valid PHP, so you could copy/paste it right back into your code if you wanted to.

Answer (score 18):

if someone needs to view arrays so cool ;) use this method.. this will print to your browser console

```
function console($obj)
{
    $js = json_encode($obj);
    print_r('<script>console.log('.$js.')</script>');
}
```

you can use like this..

```
console($myObject);
```

Output will be like this.. so cool eh !!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach($array as $v) echo $v, PHP_EOL;
```

**UPDATE**: A more sophisticated solution would be:

```
 $test = [
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
    'key3' => [
        'subkey1' => 'subval1',
        'subkey2' => 'subval2',
        'subkey3' => [
            'subsubkey1' => 'subsubval1',
            'subsubkey2' => 'subsubval2',
        ],
    ],
];
function printArray($arr, $pad = 0, $padStr = "\t") {
    $outerPad = $pad;
    $innerPad = $pad + 1;
    $out = '[' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $out .= str_repeat($padStr, $innerPad) . $k . ' => ' . printArray($v, $innerPad) . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $out .= str_repeat($padStr, $innerPad) . $k . ' => ' . $v;
            $out .= PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    $out .= str_repeat($padStr, $outerPad) . ']';
    return $out;
}

echo printArray($test);
```

This prints out:

```
    [
        key1 => val1
        key2 => val2
        key3 => [
            subkey1 => subval1
            subkey2 => subval2
            subkey3 => [
                subsubkey1 => subsubval1
                subsubkey2 => subsubval2
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: <?php foreach($data as $v) echo $v, PHP_EOL; ?> displays "Array"

Comment: Okay, then you should iterate twice foreach($raw as $array) foreach($array as $v) echo $v, PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 3):

`print_r()` is mostly for debugging.  If you want to print it in that format, loop through the array, and print the elements out.

```
foreach($data as $d){
  foreach($d as $v){
    echo $v."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it prints out the data as "Array"

Comment: @Xavier: Did you try the updated code in my answer?  You need to loop through both arrays.  `$data` is an array of arrays.

Comment: and your code worked perfectly too i just changed the /n to a <br />

Answer (score 3):

This may be a simpler solution:

```
echo implode('<br>', $data[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This tries to improve `print_r()` output formatting in console applications:

```
function pretty_printr($array) {

  $string = print_r($array, TRUE);

  foreach (preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $string) as $line) {

    $trimmed_line = trim($line);

    // Skip useless lines.
    if (!$trimmed_line || $trimmed_line === '(' || $trimmed_line === ')' || $trimmed_line === 'Array') {
      continue;
    }

    // Improve lines ending with empty values.
    if (substr_compare($trimmed_line, '=>', -2) === 0) {
      $line .=  "''";
    }

    print $line . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
[activity_score] => 0
[allow_organisation_contact] => 1
[cover_media] => Array
        [image] => Array
                [url] => ''
        [video] => Array
                [url] => ''
                [oembed_html] => ''
        [thumb] => Array
                [url] => ''
[created_at] => 2019-06-25T09:50:22+02:00
[description] => example description
[state] => published
[fundraiser_type] => anniversary
[end_date] => 2019-09-25
[event] => Array
[goal] => Array
        [cents] => 40000
        [currency] => EUR
[id] => 37798
[your_reference] => ''
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume one uses print_r for debugging. I would then suggest using libraries like [Kint](https://github.com/raveren/kint). This allows displaying big arrays in a readable format:

```
$data = [['Natural Child 1', 'Natural Child 2', 'Natural Child 3']];
Kint::dump($data, $_SERVER);
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a vanilla PHP solution, but definitely provides useful and readable output!

Answer (score 2):

One-liner for a quick-and-easy JSON representation:

```
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If using composer for the project already, require symfony/yaml and:

```
    echo Yaml::dump($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($data as $entry){
    foreach($entry as $entry2){
        echo $entry2.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//Make an array readable as string
function array_read($array, $seperator = ', ', $ending = ' and '){
      $opt = count($array);
      return $opt > 1 ? implode($seperator,array_slice($array,0,$opt-1)).$ending.end($array) : $array[0];
}
?>
```

I use this to show a pretty printed array to my visitors

Answer (score 1):

Very nice way to print formatted array in php, using the var_dump function.

```
 $a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
 var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for getting keys and their values
    $qw = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

```
while ( $ou = mysqli_fetch_array($qw) )
{
    foreach ($ou as $key => $value) 
    {
            echo $key." - ".$value."";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use online tools.

- first do print_r(your_array)
- Second copy the result and paste in http://phillihp.com/toolz/php-array-beautifier/

Comment: I just updated this to be much more robust, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

For single arrays you can use implode, it has a cleaner result to print.

```
<?php
$msg = array('msg1','msg2','msg3');
echo implode('<br />',$msg);
echo '<br />----------------------<br/>';

echo nl2br(implode("\n",$msg));
echo '<br />----------------------<br/>';
?>
```

For multidimensional arrays you need to combine with some sort of loop.

```
<?php
$msgs[] = $msg;
$msgs[] = $msg;
$msgs[] = $msg;
$msgs[] = $msg;
$msgs[] = $msg;
foreach($msgs as $msg) {
    echo implode('<br />',$msg);
    echo '<br />----------------------<br/>';
}
?>
```