# PHP - search for a key value and then find the value of another key in the same object subarray

Tags: php, search, object, multidimensional-array, podio

I've searched a lot for this, and found several similar questions, but none quite address what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to write a code that will search a PHP (multi)multidimensional array to see which subarray contains the unique key value that I have. Then I would like it to return the value of a different key in that same object subarray.

```
$Arraytosearch = Array(
.
//various other subarrays
.
[fields] => Array (
    .
    .
    .
    //I don't know the number of the object subarray

   [x] => PodioTextItemField Object (  
      [__attributes] => Array ( 
        [field_id] => 37325091 
        [type] => text 
        [external_id] => id 
        [label] => ID 
        [values] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [value] => REF100019 ) ) 

        [config] => Array ( 
            [description] => [settings] => Array ( 
                [size] => small ) 
            [required] => [mapping] => [label] => ID [visible] => 1 [delta] => 2 ) )
    .
    .
    .
     //(and so on)
```

I'd like to write a function that will return "REF100019" by supplying the value of the field_id => 37325091.

Some things I have tried that I couldn't get to work:
`foreach`
and `new RecursiveIterator` although the tutorials I read weren't useful for my case here.

Even though the array looks complicated, I think it will be easy since I already have the field id of the parent array.

Thank you in advance for any guidance or sample codes that will work!

Background: This is a part of the response I get from Podio after submitting a request to their API. I just don't know how to take that response and get the piece I need (the ID) so that I can echo it for users).

EDIT: Thank you Orangepill and Barmar for the support. I tried your code. But was getting an error, which made me realize I hadn't given you the full array. I figured out how to get the Podio response to display in a more readable format (I was reading the full JSON response before from the Podio debug file which was super confusing), and figured out the full array is actually structured as I have shown below.

I then took your code and was able to figure out how to make it work for my scenario (see below). Very proud of myself considering I have never written any code before, but I couldn't have done it without your help! Thanks again!

```
$Arraytosearch = Array(
  [items] => Array(
       [0] => PodioItem Object(
              [_attributes] => Array(
                      [fields] => Array (
                            [x] => PodioTextItemField Object (  
                                  [__attributes] => Array( 
                                         [field_id] => 37325091 
                                         [values] => Array( 
                                                [0] => Array( 
                                                     [value] => REF100019 ) )
```

Note: For anyone who is new to programming like myself and wants the Podio response (or any JSON string) to display in a "pretty" readable format like above, use the code (from [Display an array in a readable/hierarchical format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393085/display-an-array-in-a-readable-format) thanks to Phenex):

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($Arraytoformat);
print "</pre>";
```

And finally, the full code I used (using Orangepill's answer below) which searches the objects and arrays and gives me what I have been searching for for days now is as follows:

```
$Arraytosearch = PodioItem::filter(APP_ID, $filterParams);
$fieldID = 37325091;    

    function getFirstValueByFieldId($fieldId, $Arraytosearch){
      foreach($Arraytosearch["items"][0]->__attributes["fields"] as $textitem){
        if ($textitem->__attributes["field_id"] == $fieldId){
        return $textitem->__attributes["values"][0]["value"];
    }}}

$refID = getFirstValueByFieldId($fieldID, $Arraytosearch);
```

Comment: This is not just a multidimensional array, there's an object in there as well. You need to use object notation to access its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to skin this cat... this is probably the most straight forward

```
function getFirstValueByFieldId($fieldId, $Arraytosearch){
    foreach($Arraytosearch["fields"] as $textitem){
        if ($textitem->__attributes["field_id"] == $fieldId){
            return $textitems->__attributes["values"][0]["value"];

        }
    }   
}
```

to Use in your case would be

```
echo getFirstValueByFieldId("37325091", $Arraytosearch);
```

Basically it walks the elements in the fields array and returns the value in the first associated value in the values array where field_id is equal to the parameter of the function.

Comment: can you really access the attributes of an object using `$textitem["__attributes"]`? Shouldn't it be `$textitem->field_id`?

Comment: Thank you guys for the support! I was getting errors using the code, but that was my fault for providing the wrong array. I was able to figure out how to apply your solution to the actual array, and I have updated my question to reflect the final code that worked. (But your solution worked perfectly so thank you again!)

Answer (score 2):

The podio-php library has built-in methods that handle all this for you. There's no need to mess with the __attributes property yourself.

You can see a bunch of examples at https://github.com/podio/podio-php/blob/master/examples/items.php

In your case:

```
// Get item collection
$itemCollection = PodioItem::filter(APP_ID, $filterParams);
$fieldID = 37325091;

foreach ($itemCollection['items'] as $item) {
  // Get the field from the item
  $field = $item->field($fieldID);
  // Now you can print the value of that field
  print $field->humanized_value;
  // Or if you don't want to have the content sanitized:
  print $field->values[0]['value'];
}
```