# How to display result of salesforce PHP arrayp

Tags: php, salesforce

I want to display all Leads Group by City, i am using php to integrate SalesForce to my application and i have result from the query.

For simple query its not hard to display result, but for query like

"Select Count('Firstname'), City from Lead Group By City"

i am not sure how to display the array.

here is code.

```
     $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

 foreach ($response->records as $record) 
 {
    $object = get_object_vars($record);
    print_r($object);
    echo "<br />";
 }
```

and the result is like this:

```
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 4 [0] => ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 1 [0] => Atlanta, GA ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 8 [0] => Austin, TX ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 3 [0] => Baltimore, MD ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 3 [0] => Boston, MA ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 10 [0] => Central Jersey, NJ ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 17 [0] => Central VA ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 1 [0] => Chicago East, IL ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 11 [0] => Chicago West, IL ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 2 [0] => Cleveland, OH ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 5 [0] => Dallas, TX ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 3 [0] => Detroit, MI ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 2 [0] => Fitchburgh, MA ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 1 [0] => Fort Worth, TX ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 10 [0] => Hartford, CT ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 1 [0] => Houstan Cypress ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 6 [0] => Houston North, TX ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 2 [0] => Houston South, TX ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 2 [0] => Indiana, IN ) ) 
Array ( [Id] => [any] => Array ( [expr0] => 14 [0] => LA East, CA ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

As you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393085/display-an-array-in-a-readable-format), you can guide by the following to show the count:

```
foreach($object[expr0] as $child) {
    echo $child . "\n";
}
```

To print the city you have to replace `$object[expr0]` by `$object[0]`