# How can I display an array in a readable format?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to write my Array into a readable format.

```
$result = array_diff($one, $two);
print_r($result);
Array ( [1] => 298GS [2] => 09283 [3] => U4235 )
```

This is how it should look like:

```
298GS
09283
U4235
```

My only idea is to write it like this:

```
echo $result[1];
echo $result[2];
echo $result[3];
```

But this is not very useful because I never know how many values my array will have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to say, just loop through the array and show the values. This works for variable number of items

```
foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r."<br>";
}
```

Since you had difficulties doing such thing, I suggest you to study about the basics of the language (IF, lopps, variables, etc) - maybe that's what you are doing, IDK. [Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [More](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works very well! Just one question to learn: Why did people downvote my question? Didn't I ask it right?

Comment: @Jarla Sometimes I don't see the reason for downvotes, but I'd guess that it's because something like this does not require too much search to find an answer (already answered). (First result for `php show readable array` [Display an array in a readable/hierarchical format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393085/display-an-array-in-a-readable-hierarchical-format)). Also, don't forget to accept my answer if that's what you were looking for ^^.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes I am a beginner, so it is all new :D

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function as I can read the keys too, the output showed below is what you'll actually see so it is formatted.

```
function debugArray($arr)   
{
    return "<pre>" . var_export($arr, true) . "</pre>";
}

$arr = [
    1, 
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
];

echo debugArray($arr);
```

**Output**

`array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
)`

Actual image of output.

[image: Image for output.]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check `json_encode` to export your data in json format so you can use it better with UI